# Combinations of Different/Same Order/Non-order items

Tags: combinatorics

A jar contains 8 **identical** red marbles and 5 **identical** white marbles.

1. How many ways can I pick two red marbles (**order does not matter**)?
2. How many ways can I pick one red and one white (**order does not matter**)?

A jar contains 8 **different** red marbles and 5 **different** white marbles.

1. How many ways can I pick two red marbles (**order does not matter**)?
2. How many ways can I pick one red and one white (**order does not matter**)?

A jar contains 8 **identical** red marbles and 5 **identical** white marbles.

1. How many ways can I pick two red marbles (**order does matter**)?
2. How many ways can I pick one red and one white (**order does matter**)?

A jar contains 8 **different** red marbles and 5 **different** white marbles.

1. How many ways can I pick two red marbles (**order does matter**)?
2. How many ways can I pick one red and one white (**order does matter**)?

This is the same problem. I a trying to understand how the identical/different order/non-order effects the calculation. Really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $8$ red marbles, there are $\binom82=28$ ways to pick a **set** of two of them, whether the marbles are identical or not. If the marbles are identical, those $28$ sets are indistinguishable, but there are still $28$ different sets. If the order of the two marbles in the set matters, we’re no longer counting sets: we’re counting **sequences** of two marbles.

Suppose first that the marbles are all different. If we draw the one marble, replace it, and draw another, there are $8$ possible outcomes for the first draw and $8$ for the second draw, so there are $8\cdot8=64$ possible sequences of marbles. That’s referred to as drawing **with replacement**: we replace the first marble before drawing the second. But we can also draw **without replacement**. In that case there are still $8$ possible outcomes for the first draw, but no matter which of the red marbles we draw first, there are only $7$ possibilities for the second draw; this makes a total of $8\dot7=56$ possible sequences. The difference $64-56=8$ is accounted for by the $8$ sequences in which we draw the same marble twice: they’re possible if we draw with replacement, but not if we draw without replacement.

You might also notice that $56=2\cdot28$: the number of ways to draw a **sequence** of two marbles **without replacement** is twice the number of ways to draw a **set** of two marbles. That’s no coincidence: each set of two marbles can be drawn in either of two orders, so each set of two marbles corresponds to two sequences of two different marbles. (In a set the marbles are necessarily different.)

Now suppose that the $8$ red marbles are identical. **It doesn’t make any difference.** There are still $8$ marbles, so there are still $8^2=64$ possible sequences of two of them if you draw with replacement and $8\cdot7=56$ if you draw without replacement; you just can’t tell one sequence from another by eye. Even if they lack labels or other distinguishing marks, the marbles still have individual identities, and we’re counting actual sequences of marbles, not perceptibly distinguishable sequences of marbles.

> Suppose that instead of drawing two of the $8$ red marbles, I intended to distribute the $8$ marbles amongst boxes labelled $A,B$, and $C$, and I want to know the number of distinguishable ways in which I can do this. Now I’m dealing with a situation in which it **does** matter whether the marbles are identical or not.  If they are identical, it doesn’t matter which marbles go into which box: all that matters is how many marbles go into each box. Counting the distinguishable distributions is a so-called [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29), and there are $\binom{8+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{10}2=45$ distinguishable distributions. If the marbles are all different, however, we can tell the difference between the arrangement with marble $1$ in Box $A$ and all the rest in Box $B$, and the arrangement with marble $3$ in Box $A$ and all the rest in Box $B$. Now the counting is simpler: each marble can go into any one of the $3$ boxes, so assigning marbles to boxes is making a $3$-way choice $8$ times in a row. This is just an application of the multiplication principle: the choices can be made in $3^8=6561$ different ways.

Now let’s return to the jar with $8$ red and $5$ white marbles and look at the numbers of ways to get a red and a white marble when drawing two under various conditions. Here again it makes no difference whether the marbles of a given color are distinguishable or not; the only thing that matters is whether we’re drawing a **set** or a **sequence**, i.e., whether we care about the order of the two marbles. Since there are $8$ red and $5$ white marbles, there are $8\cdot5=40$ **sets** consisting of one red and one white marble; that’s the number of ways to get one marble of each color if you just grab a pair. If you draw twice in sequence, with or without replacement, each of those $40$ pairs could appear in either of two orders, so there are $2\cdot40=80$ different two-marble **sequences** consisting of one marble of each color.

---

If you use these figures to calculate the probability of some outcome, you must be sure to use the right denominator. Suppose, for instance, that you want the probability of drawing one marble of each color when you draw twice. If you draw without replacement, you can think of this as simply drawing a pair of different marbles. There are $8+5=13$ marbles, so there are $\binom{13}2=78$ different pairs of marbles, and we’ve already seen that $40$ of them contain one marble of each color, so the probability of success is $\frac{40}{78}=\frac{20}{39}\approx0.51282$.

If, on the other hand, we draw **with** replacement, then we could draw the same marble twice, so we have to count sequences, not sets. There are $13^2=169$ different sequences of two marbles, and we already saw that $80$ of them consist of one marble of each color, $40$ in the order red-white and $40$ in the order white-red. Thus, in this problem the probability of success is $\frac{80}{169}\approx0.47337$, noticeably different from the previous figure.